# Electrical quick disconnect identification

Tags: connector

Trying to correctly identify a female spade quick disconnect terminal. It is 2 mm wide (.0787") and 1 centimeter long, which includes the stem. But cannot find a source to buy from because the smallest available size seems to be .110" wide. So either I am measuring wrong or the pieces I have are custom made. How can I correctly look for a 2 mm wide female spade quick connect?[image]

Comment: They [do exist](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/terminals-quick-connects-quick-disconnect-connectors/392?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv1048=8489&sf=1&FV=-8%7C392&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25) but the minimum purchase quantity is nothing short of absurd. You may, however, be interested in [these](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/terminals-quick-connects-quick-disconnect-connectors/392?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv1048=8399&pv1048=8445&sf=1&FV=-8%7C392&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25) 1.98 or 1.93 mm ones.

Comment: Are you sure these are 2mm wide, though? They look wider than that.

Comment: ...ah, and there are also more readily available [2.36mm ones](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/terminals-quick-connects-quick-disconnect-connectors/392?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv1048=9210&sf=1&FV=-8%7C392&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25). Could your measurement have been off by a bit?

Comment: Thank you Hearth, 1.98mm is fine for project. I have ordered the items and greatly appreciate your most insightful information!